# Compare password in WordPress always return false

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to insert new user in WordPress by coding and then compare username & 
password. I tried to insert user name and password in two ways.

**1**

Insert new user code (Table - wp_users)

```
$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];//Sahil
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];//1212
$hash_value = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$user_id = wp_create_user( $userName, $hash_value, $email);
```

**2**

Tried to insert password in another way

```
$settings = array('cost' => 10, 'salt' => 'rSq.2M7Ikc.QPhVtYlp1Nu');
$hash_value = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $settings);
$user_id = wp_create_user( $userName, $hash_value, $email);
```

I didn't add code to check username & email exists in table. Above code is working properly and new user is being added in wp_users table and password is being stored in hash format. Ex. $P$BgynwP/kZuQu5p/SAU/dTMA19sbJs3/

I tried to compare it by two function,  but it always return false.

**1**

```
$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];//Sahil
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];//1212

$user = get_user_by( 'login', $userName );
$result = wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID);
if($result){
        echo 'Correct';
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong'; //Always return wrong
    }
```

**2**

```
$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];//Sahil
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];//1212
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $userName );
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $user->user_pass);
if($isPasswordCorrect){
        echo 'Correct';
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong'; //Always return wrong.
    }
```

Also tried -

```
var_dump(password_verify($password, $user->user_pass));
```

But it still return false.

Let me know, If there is any mistake in my code while comparing password or technique is wrong to do this.

Thanks

Comment: `password_hash` and  `wp_check_password` depends with two methods. It is `HASH` and `MD5`

Comment: @Abdulla - Thanks for replying. I don't have much knowledge about it. If you know can you please give me solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the plain password in `wp_create_user`, not a hash.

Comment: @A - Thanks for replying. It still doesn't work. Both are same.

Comment: @A - Yes, It works proper. If I don't use anything related to hash.If I simply insert password in normal format and compare by using this function "wp_authenticate_username_password" then it works proper. But Is it right way to do this?.

Comment: @A.Joahny `wp_authenticate_username_password` is not used to log in,is return user data is user name and password is right other wise return error

Comment: My bad. You're right. So the difference between functions is that `wp_check_password` return boolean and `wp_authenticate_username_password` return `WP_User` or `WP_Error` So @PuneetChawla you can use the function you prefer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can used [wp_authenticate_username_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password/)

Authenticate a user, confirming the username and password are valid

```
$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$userName = $_POST['txtUserName'];//Sahil
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];//1212
$check = wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $userName , $password );
```

You can then simply check the result with

```
if(is_wp_error( $check ))
{
  echo 'Wrong'; 
}
else
{
  echo 'Correct';
}
```

Create user In WordPress [wp_create_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) 
Password automatic save to database no need convert `password_hash`

```
wp_create_user( "Sahil", "1212", "Sahil@gmail.com" );
```

Comment: @PuneetChawla i think your user name and password is wrong.Create new user from back end and test with new user or check with admin user name and password . it's also working if you are not login to site

Comment: username and password are correct. Can you please test through screen sharing through Skype or teamviewer. It's urgent.

Comment: @PuneetChawla it's not possible right now. but test with created user from back end site.

Comment: @PuneetChawla `wp_authenticate_username_password()` is  WordPress default function located to user.php it's right way to authenticate a user, confirming the username and password  .it's  also working if user not login